# Since snoring can damage the nasal mechanism does snoring warrant CPAP intervention?

Tags: prevention, sleep-apnea, preventative-medicine, snore-snoring

I am not asking if [snoring can lead to damage](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2019/05/190502075830.htm) because that seems to be already known. What I'm asking is whether or not snoring should be treated as a disease in and of itself and if it warrants prescribing and treating much like Sleep Apnea.